# amdgpu-pro install fails

Tags: gpu, amdgpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu-pro

I installed Ubuntu server 20.04 and I am trying to install amdgpu-pro-20.30-1109583-ubuntu-20.04
with `sudo ./amdgpu-install -y --opencl=legacy`.

`uname -a`
Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-44-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 9 06:29:41 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The first error I had was that it couldn't find i386 packages, fine I multiarched.

But then it just failed on the install. I require the legacy for my rx 580(or so I have been told).

```
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages [108 kB]
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '20.30-1109583' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pin'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcairo2 libcdparanoia0 libdrm-amdgpu1
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libffi8ubuntu1:i386 libfontconfig1 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libllvm11
  libllvm11:i386 libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0 libopus0
  liborc-0.4-0 libpixman-1-0 libstdc++6:i386 libtheora0 libva2 libva2:i386
  libvdpau1 libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0 libvorbisenc2 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-egl1 libwayland-egl1:i386
  libwayland-server0 libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdamage1 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3
  libxfixes3:i386 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1
  libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 vdpau-driver-all
  vdpau-driver-all:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-pin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2676 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pin 20.30-1109583 [2676 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pin.
(Reading database ... 79336 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pin_20.30-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pin (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pin (20.30-1109583) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-core amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-lib amdgpu-pro-core gst-omx-amdgpu
  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu-common
  libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 libdrm2-amdgpu
  libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 libgbm1-amdgpu
  libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa
  libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libgles1-amdgpu-mesa libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libllvm10.0-amdgpu
  libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 libosmesa6-amdgpu libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386
  libxatracker2-amdgpu libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro
  xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
Suggested packages:
  libglide3 libglide3:i386
Recommended packages:
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 | libtxc-dxtn0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu amdgpu-core amdgpu-dkms amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-lib amdgpu-lib32
  amdgpu-pro-core clinfo-amdgpu-pro gst-omx-amdgpu libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1
  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu-common libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1
  libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 libdrm2-amdgpu libdrm2-amdgpu:i386
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 libgbm1-amdgpu libgbm1-amdgpu:i386
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libgles1-amdgpu-mesa libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libgles2-amdgpu-mesa
  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libllvm10.0-amdgpu libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386
  libosmesa6-amdgpu libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 libxatracker2-amdgpu
  libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro
  opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
0 upgraded, 46 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/112 MB of archives.
After this operation, 917 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms-firmware 1:5.6.5.24-1109583 [5028 kB]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms 1:5.6.5.24-1109583 [5602 kB]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-core 20.30-1109583 [2216 B]
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.100-1109583 [35.6 kB]
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-common 1.0.0-1109583 [4640 B]
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 1:2.4.100-1109583 [21.0 kB]
Get:7 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 1:2.4.100-1109583 [22.3 kB]
Get:8 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm10.0-amdgpu 1:10.0-1109583 [15.2 MB]
Get:9 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [2446 kB]
Get:10 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libglapi-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [24.7 kB]
Get:11 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:20.1.0-1109583 [7645 kB]
Get:12 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.100-1109583 [38.0 kB]
Get:13 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 1:2.4.100-1109583 [23.7 kB]
Get:14 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 1:2.4.100-1109583 [23.8 kB]
Get:15 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm10.0-amdgpu 1:10.0-1109583 [17.3 MB]
Get:16 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [2335 kB]
Get:17 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libglapi-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [24.8 kB]
Get:18 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:20.1.0-1109583 [7536 kB]
Get:19 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libxatracker2-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [1520 kB]
Get:20 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgbm1-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [31.1 kB]
Get:21 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [107 kB]
Get:22 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [4344 B]
Get:23 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [8340 B]
Get:24 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles2-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [12.0 kB]
Get:25 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx 1:20.1.0-1109583 [146 kB]
Get:26 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libosmesa6-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [3708 kB]
Get:27 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [2899 kB]
Get:28 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [2462 kB]
Get:29 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu 1:19.1.0-1109583 [58.1 kB]
Get:30 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ gst-omx-amdgpu 1.0.0.1-1109583 [58.4 kB]
Get:31 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-lib 20.30-1109583 [2136 B]
Get:32 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu 20.30-1109583 [1688 B]
Get:33 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libxatracker2-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [1323 kB]
Get:34 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgbm1-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [32.6 kB]
Get:35 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [113 kB]
Get:36 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [4344 B]
Get:37 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [8296 B]
Get:38 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles2-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.1.0-1109583 [11.9 kB]
Get:39 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx 1:20.1.0-1109583 [154 kB]
Get:40 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libosmesa6-amdgpu 1:20.1.0-1109583 [3515 kB]
Get:41 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:20.1.0-1109583 [2824 kB]
Get:42 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-lib32 20.30-1109583 [1828 B]
Get:43 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pro-core 20.30-1109583 [5556 B]
Get:44 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro 20.30-1109583 [13.8 kB]
Get:45 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ clinfo-amdgpu-pro 20.30-1109583 [149 kB]
Get:46 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd 20.30-1109583 [29.2 MB]
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms-firmware.
(Reading database ... 79349 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.6.5.24-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.5.24-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.5.24-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms.
(Reading database ... 79740 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-amdgpu-dkms_5.6.5.24-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.5.24-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-core.
Preparing to unpack .../1-amdgpu-core_20.30-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-core (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-common.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../8-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-core (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1109583) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386.
(Reading database ... 81730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1109583) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1109583) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64.
(Reading database ... 81767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../11-xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu_19.1.0-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gst-omx-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../12-gst-omx-amdgpu_1.0.0.1-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib.
Preparing to unpack .../13-amdgpu-lib_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../14-amdgpu_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../23-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.1.0-1109583_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib32.
Preparing to unpack .../24-amdgpu-lib32_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib32 (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-core.
Preparing to unpack .../25-amdgpu-pro-core_20.30-1109583_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-core (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../26-ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package clinfo-amdgpu-pro.
Preparing to unpack .../27-clinfo-amdgpu-pro_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clinfo-amdgpu-pro (20.30-1109583) ...
Selecting previously unselected package opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd_20.30-1109583_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1109583) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.5.24-1109583) ...
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.5.24-1109583 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-44-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-44-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.5.24-1109583/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.5.24-1109583); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1109583) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-core (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd:amd64 (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up clinfo-amdgpu-pro (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.0-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (20.30-1109583) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.30-1109583) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.32-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not really sure as to what I am to do next, can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after heaving some headaches I found that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the according amdgpu 20.40 works when you run it like `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install --no-32 --opencl=legacy`.

So I disabled auto upgrades and now all I have to do is make the ubuntu server less sluggish(the CPU performance is 3 % lower than the same conf I tried with debian).

Answer (score 0):

Your process is fine. Make sure you are starting with 20.04.1. Your install did an upgrade and took you to kernel 5.8.0-44. You can read [here](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/can-t-install-amdgpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-5-4-0-56-generic/td-p/426676) and [here](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amdgpu-20-40-fails-on-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-1/td-p/436134) to see that the stock kernel (5.4.0-42) or not more than 5.4.0-54 will work. To go further, bottom of the second link indicates 5.4.0-58 kernel can use amdgpu 20.45. The notes for that driver [release](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45) indicate a fix for "Ubuntu 20.04 kernel update to 5.4.0-56.62 causes compilation of its amdgpu kernel module to fail." So install without updates and [turn off automatic and unattended updates](https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) after install. Build the driver, then reconsider the update plan.

I built 20.30 on 20.04.1 last summer for mythtv with kaveri. Just noticed unattended updates took me to 5.8.0-44, glad the earlier driver build is still okay with the updates.

Comment: I couldn't get that kernel version, I went out of my way to install 18.04 LTS and I got it working by installing amdgpu-pro-install with --headless --no-32 --opencl=legacy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: AMD posted a workaround for the issue you had regarding the kernel version on the 20.45 download page. And now Driver 20.50 is out and listed to work with 20.04.2 so should install for you. Maybe will be less sluggish...

Comment: I will check it out on a dev machine, I can't take the time to have my systems down for a solution that might work. Thanks.

Comment: It does install, but it gives me an error when I try openCL applications that there are no openCL devices. Back to 18.04 ;)